# Why contextmenu in swiftUI(macOS) doesn't work?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I try to add a button in contextmenu but the action of the button it doesn't do looks like. I try to use break point and it skip the button's action in contextmenu, what's wrong with this case?
Here are the part of sample of codes.

```
@State var isWin: Bool = false

  Button(action: {
//actions
ButtonLogics.buttonLogicServ.buttonLogic(space: space, mineField: mineField)
if(space.isBomb){isLose = true}

      }, label: {
        Image(systemName: space.confStr)
          .font(.system(size: 15.5, weight: .bold))
          .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
          .contentShape(Rectangle())
          .background(space.status==true ? .gray : .blue)
      })
      .contextMenu(menuItems: {
        Button("add flag", action: {
          isWin = ButtonLogics.buttonLogicServ.buttonLogicRightSide(space: space, mineField: mineField)
          }
        )
        .alert(isPresented: $isWin, content: {
          Alert(
          title: Text("Good!"),
          message: Text("You win"),
          dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
      )
        })
    
      })
```

I check other tutorials webs that someone said it's a bug but I'm not sure, I'm a new swift developer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.